# why does printf("-%d",025); print -21? (C)

Tags: c

This might be really simple, but i was wondering why if you have this code it prints out -21?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main() {
       printf("-%d",025);
    }
```

Comment: 025 is octal == 21 decimal

Comment: Remove the `0` from `025` to have it in decimal...

Comment: Halloween equals Christmas: 31Oct == 25Dec

Comment: Mega-dupe, so duped that we need another word for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer literals starting with `0` are in octal (base 8). So `025` is `2*8 + 5` = `21`.

If you use an editor with syntax highlighting it might show you this.

Trivia: `0` itself is actually in octal for this reason, not decimal!

Answer (score 5):

025 is octal == 2 * 8 + 5 == 21 decimal

You have a minus sign in front of your integer format string placeholder, therefore it prints -21

Comment: love the fact my comment (which predates both answers) is getting more upvotes than answer. SO is really screwed up!

Comment: I started typing before your comment appeared..:)